# How to use MixCloud without Flash?

Tags: mixcloud

MixCloud forces me to use Flash, which I really don't want to use. There  doesn't appear to be any desktop app either.

Is there any way to use it without Flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using chrome, open up the console and enter;

```
localStorage['mx:use_html5_player'] = 'y';
```

Then refresh the page, and it should no longer use Flash.

*source: Email conversation with MixCloud support*